# In how many ways can $n$ different variables be related to each other?

Tags: combinatorics

Say we have three variables $x$, $y$ and $z$, which all hold an unknown value. Therefore there is a number of ways in which the variables can be ordered. I want to find the number of ways in which they can be related to each other, for example $x=y<z$ or $z<y<x$. I have already calculated the answer (which is $13$ if I am correct) using a tree, where we first select one of three possible relations between $x$ and $y$ and then for each of those, one of three possible relations between $x$ and $z$. If $x>y$ and $x>z$ we still have three possible relations between $y$ and $z$. Same reasoning if $x<y$ and $x<z$. So adding up gives $13$ possible relations. How many are there for $n$ different variables?

Comment: Are you asking for the number of ways the variables can be related by using $<$ or $=$?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig exactly. I am assuming that all the variables hold a value which we don't know, therefore there is a number of ways the variables can be ordered. I want to count those ways. So $x=y=z$ is the same as $z=x=y$ while $z<y<z$ is clearly not the same as $y<x<z$. So for some arrangements of the symbols the order matters while for others it does not.

Comment: In that case, $13$ is correct for three variables.

Comment: Refer Ordered Bell Numbers : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_Bell_number

Comment: See also https://oeis.org/A000670 (which is given on the Wikipedia page).